# staircase child always getting a 0?

Tags: c++, recursion

Hi I am a beginner in recursions.

Question:
A child is running up a staircase he can hop 1, 2 or 3 steps at a time I need to find and return the number of ways he can climb a certain stair number?

My approach:
I am trying to divide the problem into smaller base cases and add 1 when a correct ans is reached.

My code:

```
void helper(int n ,int& a){
 if(n==0){
   a = a+1;
   return;
 } 
 if(n<0)
 return;

 helper(n-1,a);
 helper(n-2,a);
 helper(n-3,a);
}


int staircase(int n){
  int ans = 0;
  helper(n,ans);
  return ans;
}
```

Problem:
I seem to be getting only `0` as answer?

Comment: Take a look at the `helper` function. Is there a path of execution where you *don't'* `return` before the recursive calls?

Comment: Whenever you post a question, make sure that you have a correct indentation of your code. This will not only help other to understand your code, but might also help you to see the problem. In your example the `helper` function will exit for any value of `n` at the `if` clause, so `a` will be zero for all `n` except if `n` is `0` then it will be `1`. No recursion will happen in you code because the `helper` after the `if` are never called.

Comment: I recommend rewriting `helper` to return a value instead of using a reference parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why your code won't work. Here is a demo of it working with some changes: [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ede58a5805be67e3/)

It is recommended that you don't pass in a reference and rather make each sub-problem which is either step 1, 2 or 3 self contained problems where you combine the results and that is the final answer similar to:

```
int staircase_without_reference(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    if(n < 0) return 0;

    return staircase(n - 1) + staircase(n - 2) + staircase(n - 3);   
}
```

This returns the similar to your program without the reference parameter.

Comment: Please check that live demo - Edit: fixed.